# How to generate Release Notes for Milestones?

Tags: gitlab, release-notes

So I was wondering how you guys handle generating of release notes for let's say a milestone in GitLab.

What I want is to have for every Issue an option to write some text that is considered a "Release Note".

Then I want an option to automatically generate i.e.: a text file that contains all those indivudual Release Notes.

Any best practices on how to realize this?

Comment: This question is similar to the stack overflow question: [Automatic release notes in gitlab [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60147132/automatic-release-notes-in-gitlab)