# How to automate release notes generation in gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'm seeking assistance in automating the generation of release notes in GitLab. Is there a recommended method or tool that allows for this automated process? I'd appreciate any insights or guidance on how to achieve this effectively.
Thank you!

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/66320602/6309

Comment: `git log --pretty=oneline HEAD...1.0.0 --decorate=False` where `1.0.0` is your previous tag

Answer (score 1):

You can use the API to list all issues in a milestone, see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/milestones.html#get-all-issues-assigned-to-a-single-milestone

There is no feature to create release notes from a milestone, or from annotated tags. The issue is being tracked at https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/15563

EDIT:

some work regarding Release Notes has been implemented in 12.9: see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/releases/#add-release-notes-to-git-tags

Comment: no i meant like this https://github.com/jk1z/gitlab-release-note-generator

Comment: well yes, that's a third party library implementing the missing feature

Answer (score 0):

I have developed a Python lib to generate release notes or changelog automatically, listing merge requests since the last release of a GitLab repository.
The source code is here with instructions on how to use it: https://github.com/vuillaut/gitlab_release_notes

You may use the online app here for a more convenient approach:
https://purl.org/gitlab_release_notes/app